# Why in CPP in some system the RAND_MAX is set to 32K while in others it is 2147483647

Tags: c++, random, random-seed

In my CPP system whenever I generate a random number using rand() I always get a value between 0-32k while in some online videos and codes it is generating a value between 0-INT_MAX. I know it is dependent on RAND_MAX. So it there some way to change this value such that generated random number are of the range 0-INT_MAX
Thanks in advance for the help :)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
        cout << rand() << endl;
    }
}
```

I used this code and the random number generated are
5594
27457
5076
5621
31096
14572
1415
25601
3110
22442

While the same code on online compiler gives
928364519
654230200
161024542
1580424748
35757021
1053491036
1968560769
1149314029
524600584
2043083516

Comment: Why, in the year of our Lord two thousand twenty two, are you using `rand()` in your C++ code?

Comment: Just want to know the reason behind this behaviour of different RAND_MAX ranges in different systems

Comment: The fact that it can differ should be enough. Without looking at the standard, a very educated guess is that it's implementation defined. There isn't a further explanation required.

Comment: [RAND_MAX](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX)

Comment: "So is there some way to change this value". `RAND_MAX` is not a configuration setting. It tells you what already happened (in the implementation of `rand()`). It's like saying, "the ingredients panel of this snack says it has 200 calories. How can I change it to 100 calories?"

Comment: "but due to some time constraints while online contest" -- if some contest forces you to write this sort of code, it might be wise to avoid it. You're likely to just learn bad habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rand()` is a very old function, going back to the earliest days of C.  In those early days, an `INT_MAX` of 32k was common and well justified.  Surely it's easy to see that `RAND_MAX > INT_MAX` doesn't make any sense.

As for why some compilers have updated their `RAND_MAX` in the intervening years and some have not, I would guess that it's down to a commitment to backwards compatibility.  I know that I've been personally bitten by the 32k limit in Microsoft's compiler.  But Microsoft has long been a champion of backwards compatibility, so I'll forgive them on this one.

Since C++11 there's a bunch of new [random number functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that have been introduced.  They're better than the old `rand()` in almost every way, except perhaps for ease of use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Don't use `rand()`. There are many reasons to not use `rand()`, not the least of which is that it is one of the two worst random number generators ever widely distributed. (The other is [RANDU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANDU).) Don't use `rand()`. Ever.

Look for `random()` and `arc4random()` on your system. If you don't find those, then use the PCG source code [here](https://www.pcg-random.org/download.html).

Comment: Yup I always use the random() for generating the random numbers but due to some time constraints while online contest I tried using this code then noticed this behaviour. So just need to know the reason behind this.

Comment: It's debatable which is worse, `rand()` or [`randu`](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/RANDU). Knuth felt pretty strongly about the latter, he described it as "[truly horrible"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANDU).

Comment: I disagree with the premise of "Don't use `rand()`. Ever.".     I certainly wouldn't use it production code where I care about properties (distribution, etc) of the random numbers produced.   But `rand()` is easy to set up and use, and much more convenient than alternatives (for example, when producing a small number of random values to test other code, and the actual inputs to that other code don't matter).

Comment: I'm missing how `rand()` is much more convenient, or even slightly more convenient than `random()`. Is it that there are two fewer characters to type?

Comment: @MarkAdler -- `rand()` is much more convenient because when I call it in my code it compiles. If I call `random()` it doesn't.